# Allow only folders and files in NSOpenPanel

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel

In  my application I need to support folders and files selection. So far I have these settings

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [[NSOpenPanel alloc] init];
[openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[openPanel setCanCreateDirectories:NO];
```

But with this anyone can choose `.app` files(folders in reality). I see that there is an option for setting allowed file types which doesnt work here as I need a wildcard file selection and exclude only particular types.

Is there any way to exclude these files ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`- (BOOL)panel:(id)sender shouldEnableURL:(NSURL *)url`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOpenSavePanelDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008249-CH1-SW4)
 of the `NSOpenSavePanelDelegate`. Inside this use NSURL to get the UTI and check it against your accepted types list. [Full List of UTI-Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008771-CH100-SW2). You could also negate the logic to exclude the unsupported types, whichever is more appropriate to your app and what your users expect. If you can evaluate the file fast enough, you may even open it and then enable or disable it in the Panel.

```
- (BOOL)panel:(id)sender shouldEnableURL:(NSURL *)url
    NSString* itemUTI = nil;
    NSError* outErr = nil;
    BOOL showInPanel = NO;

    BOOL success = [url getResourceValue:&itemUTI NSURLTypeIdentifierKey error:&outErr];
    if ( ! success || nil == itemUTI) {
        // handle failure
    } else {
        showInPanel = UTTypeConformsTo(itemUTI, kUTTypeData) || UTTypeConformsTo(itemUTI, kUTTypeFolder);
    }

    return showInPanel;
}
```

Comment: @user88975 did my answer help you? if yes, would you care to mark it as accepted using the checkmark left?